# using factor in ggplot for python

Tags: python-ggplot

I'm having trouble using factor in ggplot for python.  Here is the R code that I want to re-create in python.

```
library('ggplot2')
head(iris)
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width)) + geom_point(aes(colour=factor(Species)))
```

In python I do the following:

```
from ggplot import *
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
iris = load_iris()
ggplot(iris.data, aes(iris.data[:, x_index], iris.data[:, y_index])) \
+ geom_point(aes(colour = iris.target)) + xlab('x axis') + ylab('y axis')
```

I keep getting errors.   I believe this has to do with the factor part.  I can't set to a factor and then allow it to plot.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't know what `load_iris()` produces, but I supect that it is not a pandas dataframe. you probably want `iris_df = pandas.DataFrame(iris.data.data, columns=iris.feature_names); iris_df["flower_types"] = iris.target`. Afterwards you should be able to use the column names (`iris_df.columns`) to specify the `aes` and `colour`. You don't need factor if `iris_df["flower_types"]` is of dtype string -> ggplot automatically uses strings as if they were factors (unfortunately you can't reorder them :-()